# Spring Cloud config server security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I implemented Spring Cloud config server. How can I prevent the config server `bootstrap.yml` file from storing the GIT user name and password as clear text?

Comment: Try to use `SSH connection` with `public/private keys` instead of https with user and password.  SSH keys should be stored in `~/.ssh/ catalog`.

Comment: In that way we are exposing the private key, ​hostKeyAlgorithm etc. i want my cloud config server to be secured. Can i add my username and password on AWS secure manager?

Comment: Yes, you can put all configs into `AWS Parameter store` and put server credentials to `~/.aws/credentials`. To use that You need to have `Spring Cloud AWS `

Comment: No i dont want to use Spring Cloud AWS, I have implemented the spring cloud config server and instead of adding GIT password on bootstrap.yml file, can i put it in AWS secrets manager? If yes how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok So this is working fine for me, the issue was my config server's bootstrap.yml need to connect to GIT repository as backend and GIT repo is secured with username and password but I can not pass the username and password in bootstrap.yml file.

To solve this:

Pass the credential as environmental variable and store these environment variable in terraform or any other secure location.

Answer (score 0):

Vault: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault

Use Vault: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/#_vault

Set up Spring Vault:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-vault/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/

https://spring.io/projects/spring-vault

In your Spring Cloud config server, file `bootstrap.yml`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      token: YourVaultToken
```